# Como crear un oyente de teclado solo para la tecla ENTER?

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy trabajando con una ventana de registro de usuarios, y al final tengo el boton registrar, pero quiero que el usuario cuando aprete la tecla enter, haga lo mismo como si le hiciera click al boton registrar, como puedo hacer eso? he visto que los oyentes de teclados funcionan con todas las teclas pero solo quiero para la tecla enter

Comment: De componente es un JtextField  para el formulario?

Comment: Si, son 4 campos Jtextfield de registro

Answer (score 2):

Dado que son campos JTextField, lo único que tienes que haces es añadir un listener.

myJTextField.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

     //Lo que debería hacer

}});
```

esto al presionar el enter te realizará lo puesto en el comentario

También puedes controlar el presionado de cada tecla con el listener de key, que en este caso si solo vas a usar el press es recomendable el adapter

```
myJTextField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){
           //la acción a realizar
        }
    }

});
```